# Apache Alias Directory

Tags: apache, webserver, alias, directory

How can I use an Alias Directory as a subdomain, for example when I use my subdomain http://subdomain.domain.com and I click a link I go to http://subdomain.domain.com/new-link but when I use an Alias http://domain.com/Alias and I click a link I go to http://domain.com/new-link and I want to go to http://domain.com/Alias/new-link it means I want to mantain http://domain.com/Alias/

¿Any Ideas?

Comment: That would require.. relative to path url's in the links (`'./new-link'` instead of `'/new-link'`  or `http://domain.com/new-link`)...

Comment: I want to work with subdomains and Aliases at the same time, and I don't have a lot of time for changing my links. Is it possible through .htaccess?

Comment: No, not in any reliable way without actually changing the links, the only way would be a brittle redirect-fest relying on referer headers, which are spotty at best. And why use both? Google doesn't like duplicates, users don't like duplicates, why do you?

Comment: 'cause I have http://client.domain.com and I want to migrate them to https://domain.com/client

Comment: If you want to _migrate_, there's no reason to keep the old subdomain, is there? In that case, yes, it's possible to use some `RewriteCond`'s matching `%{HTTP_HOST}`.

Comment: ok in that case (I won't maintain the old subdomain), what is the correct .htaccess?

Answer (score 0):

For migrating your subdomain to the subdirectory (I assume permanent external redirects, Google likes those, people with bookmarks too):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} client.domain.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/client$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

If you mean multiple subdomains, this would work too:

```
#do not rewrite www.
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.
#rewrite al other subdomains
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} (.*).domain.com 
RewriteRule (.*) http://domain.com/%1$1 [L,R=301,QSA]
```

Comment: But when I click in a link `When I was in subdomain.domain.com an I clicked in a link I went to subdomain.domain.com/new-link, currently when I click in the alias domain.com/alias I go to domain.com/new-link but I want to go to domain.com/alias/new-link`

Comment: Ah, back to the `./new-link` vs. `/new-link`, hard to fix unless you add  a `<base>` element to the `<head>`.

Comment: The links _should_ change, but you may be stressed for time now I understand. Is your website fixed html, or is some technology involved? In PHP for instance, I'd throw everything in an output buffer an rewrite `href="/` occurrences...

Comment: how did you rewrite them?, I'm using PHP with Zend FK

Comment: BTW: forcing them all to your subdomain (`subdomain.domain.com/some/link`) would _also_ fix things, as that would be rewritten constantly.

Comment: Rewriting? With your standard string inspecting tools (regexes, or an HTML parser, depends on what documents)

Comment: I don't want to use subdomains! I'm migrating from subdomins to aliases! 'cause I want to use my https

Comment: You have a few options: (1) rewrite your urls to use `./` rather then `/` (2) rewrite your urls to an `/alias/` - prefix rather then `/` (3)  rewrite your urls to an `subdomain.exeample.com/` - prefix rather then `/` (4) Do any of 1,2,3 with code (either once over & store, or continuously). Those are your options, I cannot think of other ones.